# Region of Convergence of power series

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

The power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n} z^{2n} $ converges if
a)$|z|\le 2$
b)$|z|\lt 2$
c)$|z|\le\sqrt2$
d)$|z|\lt\sqrt 2$
I tried this problem,my answer is d).I am not sure whether it is correct or not.It can be c).My question is how to check convergence of the series on the boundary of region and it is depend on function.Can anyone explain why and how?

Comment: Why not to consider $\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^{-n} z^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ using $x=\frac{z^2} 2$ ? I am sure that this would make life easier.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Why don't you write that as answer?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

When you face things such as

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^{n} z^{bn}$$ just rewrite it as $$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (az^b)^{n}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n}$$ where $x=az^b$. So, you are always back to the same problem.

For your specific case, $a=\frac 12$ and $b=2$.

**Edit**

Let us make it more complex $$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^{bn+c} z^{dn}=a^c\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^{bn} z^{dn}=a^c\sum_{n=0}^\infty \big(a^{b} z^{d}\big)^n$$ Now, define $x=a^b z^d$ to go back to the simple situation.

Comment: Ok but correct answer is C.I don't understand why?

Comment: For me the correct answer is $d)$. Remember that, by the end , $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n}=\frac{1}{1-x}$. Probably, one more typo in a book.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are very welcome !

Answer (score 1):

$$\rho =\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n |}=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[2n]{|2^{-n} |} =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Hence $R=\frac{1}{\rho}=\sqrt{2}.$
So the answer d) is correct.